# Parsing measurement units

Tags: c#, regex, parsing

I have the following string:

```
string value = "123.456L";
```

What is the best way to parse this string into a string and a double:

```
double number = 123.456;
string measure = "L"
```

Instead of the L, we could also have something else, like `oz`, `m/s`, `liter`, `kilograms`, etc

Comment: I think you just nailed it, declare as two strings. For anything more, you need to provide more details.

Comment: That depends. Do you always know that the last character will be the measure letter you're looking for? If not, what might your other potential inputs look like?

Comment: In the end we might have any kind of measure, could be l, oz, etc.

@YuriyFaktorovich, this is coming from a text input

Comment: For that particular string, @YuriyFaktorovich is right. You need to add more detail, will it always be a single letter, will it never have a space between the number and the measurement, should it work for measures like m/s, etc...

Comment: Are you looking for a C# equivalent to `strtod`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming that the units of measure are always expressed as a single character at the back of the string, you can do this:

```
string value = "123.456L";
var pos = value.LastIndexOfAny("0123456789".ToCharArray());
double number = double.Parse(value.Substring(0, pos+1));
string measure = value.Substring(pos+1);
```

Comment: I'd use `IndexOf("L")`. It's clearer what the intent is. My $0.02

Comment: @Yuck I am not sure if the value is always `L`, but if it is, then you are right.

Comment: If the unit isn't expressed as a single character, you'd need to build a regex to catch the allowed abbreviations, I'd guess.

Comment: @Oded Well, it's no longer implicit - this is the first thing I spelled out in the "under the radar" edit to my answer :)

Comment: @Schiavini I edited the answer to reflect the edit to your question.

Comment: @Dave No, `LastIndexOfAny` would be sufficient. A regex to match doubles is a lot trickier than it may seem.

Comment: `LastIndexOfAny` only works if the suffix itself doesn't contain any more digits. I mean, `m2` for square meters is not unheard of. So it's better to scan for the first char that can't be part of a double. (digits, periods, commas, plus, minus, e and E)

Comment: This looks very good. The only problem is the dot, that could differ per region

Comment: @MrLister This becomes more complex than the initial edit of the question rather rapidly: if we to allow the `e` notation, we must be extra careful with units containing `e` (`eV`s for example).

Comment: @Schiavini This solution does not rely upon dot being the decimal separator. It does require that the unit of measure did not contain digits (i.e. mSq instead of m2 for square meters, etc.)

Comment: you are right, because you're getting the last index. Thank you

Comment: I was thinking of making a regex that matched a specific list of possible abbreviations that were always at the end of the string, so you wouldn't have to try to parse the float.

Answer (score 6):

Based on the comment explaining the input, I'd use Regex.

```
double number = double.Parse(Regex.Match(value, @"[\d.]+").Value);
string measure = value.Replace(number.ToString(), "");
```

The regex `[\d.]` will match any number or `.`, the `+` means it must be for 1 or more matches.

Comment: It looks good, but `double.Parse(Regex.Match("123.312HHH", @"[\d.]+").Value) = 123312.0`

Comment: A regex for matching float/double numbers is quite a bit more complex: `[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?`

Comment: @Schiavini not sure how you got that, [here](http://ideone.com/Cakp8) is a test showing otherwise.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight that's true, but this seems like all that's needed here.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it like this:

```
public bool TryParseUnit ( string sValue, out double fValue, out string sUnit )
{
    fValue = 0;
    sUnit = null;

    if ( !String.IsNullOrEmpty ( sValue ) )
    {
        sUnit = GetUnit ( sValue );

        if ( sUnit != null )
        {
            return ( Double.TryParse ( sValue.Substring ( sValue.Length - sUnit.Length ),
                out fValue );
        }
    }

    return ( false );
}

private string GetUnit ( string sValue )
{
    string sValue = sValue.SubString ( sValue.Length - 1 );

    switch ( sValue.ToLower () )
    {
        case "l":
            return ( "L" );
    }

    return ( null );
}
```

I know it's more complicated than the other answers but this way you can also validate the data during parsing and discard invalid input.

Comment: your solutions doesn't cope with the matter that there is more than an L, could be longer, could be different.

Comment: @ShegitBrahm I know, but adding that is a trivial matter.

Comment: @xxbbcc the problem is that it can get messy if there are different combinations of letters. You can have so many combinations that the switch statement could grow unwieldy.

Comment: @Jetti I agree with you, it can get unwieldy but a `switch` statement will be pretty much the only choice when it comes to handling multiple units. Doing regular expressions to pick up the different parts may help separating the number from the unit name but I look at that only as an intermediate step, not as the parsing solution because it does no validation. I prefer validation to happen during parsing because that way the main code doesn't have to be polluted with validation logic - the TryParse function will simply return `true`/`false`.

Comment: @xxbbcc another option (not necessarily better) is loading a HashSet<T> with the possible values and then doing Contains(unit of measure). That way the details are left elsewhere and when parsing you just have to deal with a true or false

Comment: @Jetti yes, you're right, a `HashSet` would also work to look up the right unit name. It may even have the same performance as the switch statement because string-based switches are usually turned into hash tables by the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with a regex

```
        using System.Text.RegularExpression;
        Regex reg = new Regex(@"([\d|\.]*)(\w*)");
        string value = "123.4L";
        MatchCollection matches = reg.Matches(value);
        foreach (Match match in matches)
        {
            if (match.Success)
            {

                GroupCollection groups = match.Groups;
                Console.WriteLine(groups[1].Value); // will be 123.4
                Console.WriteLine(groups[2].Value); // will be L

            }
        }
```

So what this will do is look for a 0 or more digits or "." and then group them and then look for any character (0 or more). You can then get the groups from each match and get the value. This will work if you want to change the type of measurement and will work if you don't have a decimal point either.

---

Edit: It is important to note that you must use groups[1] for the first group and groups[2] for the second group. If you use group[0] it will display the original string.

Comment: Thank you!
but `new Regex(@"([\d|\.]*)(\w*)").Matches("123.312HHH")[0]` results in the whole string again: 123.312HHH

Comment: @Schiavini [0] is the whole string. [1] is the first group and [2] is the second group. I'll edit to be more clear.

Comment: on my test, [0] was the whole string, [1] was empty and [2] didn't exist

Comment: @Schiavini double check you entered everything correctly. I ran this through IdeOne and it worked perfectly. Check it out [here](http://ideone.com/AIDf6)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at Units.NET on [GitHub](https://github.com/angularsen/UnitsNet) and [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/UnitsNet/). It supports parsing abbreviations in different cultures, but it is still on my [TODO list](https://github.com/angularsen/UnitsNet/issues/30) to add support for parsing combinations of numbers and units. I have already done this on a related project, so it should be straight-forward to add.

**Update Apr 2015:** You can now parse units and values by `Length.Parse("5.3 m");` and similar for other units.

Comment: This question is more than 2 years old, but thanks for the reference, it looks great!

Comment: Even old questions may be shining gems when googling.

Answer (score 0):

Simply spoken: look for all characters that are 0..9 or . and trim them to a new string, then have last part in second string. In a minute I cann give code.

Edit: Yes, I meant digits 0-9, corrected it. But easier is to get index of last number and ignore stuff before for the trimming.

Comment: @Schiavini If it has, I can't find it. [Here](http://samcragg.wordpress.com/2012/01/26/strtod-in-c-part-1-the-specification/) is an implementation of `strtod` in C#, but it's a _lot_ of code.

Comment: i didn't add any code any longer because others where faster with (maybe) more efficient solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
string ma = Regex.Match(name, @"((\d\s)|(\d+\s)|(\d+)|(\d+\.\d+\s))(g\s|kg\s|ml\s)").Value;
```

this will match:

40 g , 40g , 12.5 g , 1 kg , 2kg , 150 ml ....